# 25 at twenty-five!

Tags: discussion

As well as reaching a personal landmark, it's also a site landmark when I became the 25th member to hit 25k reputation yesterday (narrowly beaten to the line by two others - you know who you are).

I believe that's a great sign that this site is in fine health, and bodes well for the future.  It's interesting to reflect back a few years to see [how we were doing as a Beta site](/q/991) and see how far we have come - that description feels like a different universe!

Let's all raise a (virtual) glass to the continued success of Code Review!

Comment: Congrats for reaching 25k!

Comment: Congrats [Mathias Ettinger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718) and [Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493) aswell. Congrats on the three of you getting it within two days of eachother!

Comment: Congrats Toby and thanks for contributing to the site! :-)

Answer (score 29):

Congratultions, Toby. Perhaps now is a good time to dig up some metrics on the site activity and progress. I built these SEDE queries a while ago, and running them again is a good thing.

First up, is [a badge-ranking query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199310/site-badge-rankings). Code Review ranks as 21 out of 173 Stack Exchange sites in this query. I consider this to be a pretty good indicator of how well "populated" this site is compared to others. For example, we have more participation than many other, more high-profile sites like Apple, Programmers, StackOverflowEs and StackOverflowJa

Next is my long-time activity chart: [Site Activity and Vote Graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=180#graph) ... which indicates a bit of a dip over the past 3 years:

[image: Site Activity]

Running the same query over back to 2013 is more interesting:

[image]

In general, the site is doing well, but is "settling" in terms of activity.

Maybe seeing some of the charts will inspire others as well.... it is inspiring me to answer more, I think!

Comment: In my EE days, I'd have wanted to 'Fourier-Transform' that graph!